# Protect my source code from end user

Tags: php, linux, security

I have PHP script that do something. My customer has his own server. I don't want him to see source code but the script must running on his server.

Is there any technique to do that? Something like encryption or something else? I'm looking for encryption technique or something else that I don't know right now.

Server is linux-based.

Comment: [base64_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php) your source code

Comment: it's just encoding... base64_decode will show him source code.

Comment: The best technique to protect your source code is with a strong agreement, and a lawyer

Comment: @MarkBaker I know that but I'm looking for some other technique.

Comment: @Thamizhan He is looking without encryption.

Comment: "I don't want him to see source code" — Write a software license that gives you the protections you think you need.

Comment: @Quentin You are really the best...

Comment: for duplicate questions :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a commercial solution, two of the most popular products are [ionCube PHP encoder](http://www.ioncube.com/) and [zendguard](http://www.zend.com/en/products/zend-guard) . There are a few free solutions too like [PHP protect](http://www.phpprotect.info/) but I haven't personally used any of them. Search for `php obfuscator/encoder` to find the kind of software you require.

Comment: I will check that tools.

Comment: Thank you @R Singh It helps me...